# Trying to correct a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I currently have the following query;

```
SELECT a.schedID,
a.start AS eventDate, b.div_id AS divisionID, b.div_name AS divisionName
FROM schedules a
INNER JOIN divisions b ON b.div_id = a.div_id
WHERE date_format(a.start, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2010-01-01'
AND DATE_ADD(a.start, INTERVAL 5 DAY) <= CURDATE()
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT results_id FROM results e WHERE e.schedID = a.schedID)
ORDER BY eventDate ASC;
```

Im trying to basically find any schedules that do not have any results 5 days after the schedule date. My current query has major performance issues. It also times out inconsistently. Is there a different way to write the query? Im at a mental roadblock. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without antcipating much on the outcome I would suggest the following leads :
* try to remove the date_format as this generates one function call per record. I don't know the format of your column a.start but this should be possible.
* same for DATE_ADD, you could probably put it on the other member like :

```
a.start <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAYS)
```

you get a chance the result is cached rather than being calculated for each line, you could even define it as a parameter upfront
* the NOT EXISTS is very expensive, it seems to mee you could replace this by a left join like :

```
schedules a LEFT JOIN results e ON a.schedId = e.schedId WHERE e.schedId is NULL
```

- double-check that all join fields are well indexed.

Good luck

Comment: Greg, you were right on track. NOT EXISTS is expensive in terms of performance vs. is NULL. I used the LEFT JOIN and it appears to have solved the issue. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT 
    a.schedID, a.start AS eventDate, b.div_id AS divisionID, b.div_name AS divisionName
FROM
    schedules a
    INNER JOIN divisions b ON b.div_id = a.div_id
WHERE
    date_format(a.start, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2010-01-01'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            results e
            INNER JOIN schedules a2 ON e.schedID = a2.schedID
        WHERE
            DATE_ADD(a2.start, INTERVAL 5 DAY) <= CURDATE()
            AND a2.id = a.id
    )
ORDER BY eventDate ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

dont know if mysql is same as oracle but are you converting a date to a string here and then comparing it with a string '2010-01-01' ?  Can you convvert 2010-01-01 to a date instead so that if there is an index on a.start, it can be used ?

Also does this query definitely return the right answer ?

You mention you want schedules without results 5 days after the schedule date but it looks like you are aksing for anything in the last 5 days ?

a.start >= 1-Jan-10 and start date + 5 days is before today

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT a.schedID,
       a.start AS eventDate,
       b.div_id AS divisionID,
       b.div_name AS divisionName
  FROM (SELECT * FROM schedules s WHERE DATE(s.start) >= '2010-01-01' AND DATE_ADD(s.start, INTERVAL 5 DAY) <= CURDATE()) a
 INNER JOIN divisions b
    ON b.div_id = a.div_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT results_id FROM results) e
    ON e.schedID = a.schedID
 WHERE e.results_id = ''
 ORDER BY eventDate ASC;
```